# Toggle user confirmation not working

Tags: yii2

I am working on an application with user platform shown below:

[image: UserConfirmation]

**Controller**

```
 public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}  

    public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new UserSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

**Model**

```
    public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'user_id' => Yii::t('app', 'User ID'),
        'user_login_id' => Yii::t('app', 'User Login ID'),
        'user_password' => Yii::t('app', 'Password'),
        'user_type' => Yii::t('app', 'User Type'),
        'is_block' => Yii::t('app', 'Block Status'),
        'is_confirmed' => Yii::t('app', 'Block Status'),
        'confirmed_at' => Yii::t('app', 'Date Confirmed'),
        'created_at' => Yii::t('app', 'Created At'),
        'created_by' => Yii::t('app', 'Created By'),
        'updated_at' => Yii::t('app', 'Updated At'),
        'updated_by' => Yii::t('app', 'Updated By'),
        'current_pass' => Yii::t('app','Current Password'),
        'new_pass' => Yii::t('app','New Password'),
        'retype_pass' => Yii::t('app', 'Retype Password'),
        'admin_user' => Yii::t('app', 'Admin Username'),
        'create_password' => Yii::t('app', 'Password'),
        'confirm_password' => Yii::t('app', 'Confirm Password'),

    ];
}
```

**View**

```html
<?php Pjax::begin() ?>
<div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-body">
        <?=
        GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'layout' => "{items}\n{pager}",
            'columns' => [        
                'user_login_id',
                'user_type',

        [
   'attribute' => 'created_at',
   'value' => function ($data) {
     return (!empty($data->created_at) ? Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($data->created_at) : ' - ');
    },            
        ], 
                
                        [
                            'header' => Yii::t('urights', 'Confirmation'),
                            'value' => function ($model) {
                                if (!$model->is_confirmed) {
                                    return '<div class="text-center"><span class="text-success">' . Yii::t('urights', 'Confirmed') . '</span></div>';
                                } else {
                                    return Html::a(Yii::t('urights', 'Confirm'), ['confirm', 'id' => $model->user_id], [
                                                'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-success btn-block',
                                                'data-method' => 'post',
                                                'data-confirm' => Yii::t('urights', 'Are you sure you want to confirm this user?'),
                                    ]);
                                }
                            },
                                    'format' => 'raw',
                                ],                                           
                    
                                [
                                    'header' => Yii::t('urights', 'Block status'),
                                    'value' => function ($model) {
                                        if ($model->is_block) {
                                            return Html::a(Yii::t('urights', 'Unblock'), ['block', 'id' => $model->user_id], [
                                                        'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-success btn-block',
                                                        'data-method' => 'post',
                                                        'data-confirm' => Yii::t('urights', 'Are you sure you want to unblock this user?'),
                                            ]);
                                        } else {
                                            return Html::a(Yii::t('urights', 'Block'), ['block', 'id' => $model->user_id], [
                                                        'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-block',
                                                        'data-method' => 'post',
                                                        'data-confirm' => Yii::t('urights', 'Are you sure you want to block this user?'),
                                            ]);
                                        }
                                    },
                                            'format' => 'raw',
                                        ],                                    
                
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                    'template' => '{update} {delete}',
                ],
                ],
            ]);
        ?>                
    </div>
</div>        
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

As shown in the diagram, when I click on Confirm (Green Button), it shown disable the button and turn it to **Confirmed**. Then set is_confimred to 0 (zero).

Also, if I click on Block (Red Button), it should change the button caption to unblock and set is_block to 0.

However, I am not getting result, but I have the page shown below:

[image: Error]

How do I resolve it?

Comment: show your controller code with behaviour

Comment: Add `confirm` action code.

Comment: I have added the controller code with behaviour. Check it from the original code. But I don't have anything for confirm action code? How do I do that.  '     public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }  '

Answer (score 0):

You should add toggle functions for both confirm and block to the controller.

```
public function actionConfirm($id)
{
    if(($model = User::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        $model->is_confirmed = $model->is_confirmed ? false : true;
        $model->update();
    }

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}

public function actionBlock($id)
{
    if(($model = User::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        $model->is_block = $model->is_block ? false : true;
        $model->update();
    }

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```